# Gauss-Seidel failing for large square symmetric (positive definite) matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am facing an issue where, due to the applications, my square symmetric matrices have become too large ($500 \times 500$) to invert via eigendecomposition with the QR algorithm (triangularization, upper Hessenberg form, etc.)  Typically, for smaller problems, I always  use the QR algorithm and exploit the Principal Axis Theorem where my matrix is defined as $\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\mathbf{E}^{\mathsf{T}}$, where $\mathbf{E}$ are the eigenvectors and $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

Specifically, I am using the Newton-Raphson method for solving a system of non-linear equations, where the the solution updates are $\mathbf{x}^{(t+1)}=\mathbf{x}^{(t)} + \mathbf{s}\mathbf{H}^{-1}$.   As you know the inverse $\mathbf{H}^{-1}$ is merely $\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\mathsf{T}}$.  In order to reduce compute times, I would like to transition to Gauss-Seidel (SOR) or conjugate-gradient.

Assuming a particular problem involving a $500 \times 500$ matrix, it is working out that conjugate gradient, Gauss-Seidel, and SOR ($1<\omega<2$) are bombing out, that is, the update vector elements in $\mathbf{s}\mathbf{H}^{-1}$ start to grow, instead of becoming smaller.  However, eigendecomposition via the QR algorithm seems to work all the time, with the exception of much longer wait times.  I checked for pathologies in $\mathbf{H}$ and it is surely positive definite -- so that's not what's impeding Gauss-Seidel.

The only thing I can think of that's allowing only the QR algorithm to work is that QR first reduces the matrix to a tridiagonal form (tred) via Householder, then feeds results into the QR algorithm (tqli).  Thus, I think if I rearrange $\mathbf{H}$ and force greater values toward the diagonal, then Gauss-Seidel or conjugate gradient may have a chance.

Question is, is there a well-known algorithm that can reorder off-diagonal elements $h_{jk}$ so that $\mathbf{H}$ is more diagonally dominant?  Gauss-Seidel is known to converge if (a) the matrix is symmetric or (b) is diagonally dominant.  However, it is appearing that if a symmetric matrix becomes very large, then property (b) above tends to swamp criterion (a).

**UPDATE**

I made the $\sim 500 \times \sim 500$ covariance matrix diagonally dominant, but did not get Guass-Seidel to converge. I have seen comments online suggesting that Gauss-Seidel seems to be more appropriate for "more linear" problems.  My specific application is for maximum likelihood problems where the score and Hessian matrices are the first and second partial derivatives of the log of the likelihood function w.r.t. the regression parameters -- in my case logistic regression.

Comment: Can this be done with higher precision? I assume it is already double. How about quad?

Comment: @Marty - see the UPDATE section - making the Hessian diagonally dominant did not help.   I am already using double-precision reals, so are you suggesting 128-bit?  FYI - I do know a package for logistic, Poisson, Cox PH maximum likelihood regression models (multiplicative, non-linear) that I used years ago in which the authors stated they implemented Gauss-Seidel "to avoid matrix inversion."  So I am guessing they actually overcame what I am dealing with.  I think Gauss-Seidel is not sensitive to strong curvature due to the second partial derivatives in the Hessian matrix elements(?)